# Angular 1.5: Directive using link function won't update the parent scope through the bindings

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm creating a directive to wrap the [DateRangePicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/). I'm using the link function to instantiate the daterangepicker and I attach a callback method on the directive's controller to update the scope variables. Problem is it doesn't seem to update those variables. I've made a PLNKR to demonstrate the issue I'm having. You can see that `startDate` and `endDate` update fine using the buttons. And in the `console` debug section you can see that the callback method is being called. It just doesn't update the parent scope. And you can tell that it does bind with one-way because the `label` shows up as `Schedule`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/s8sB95YwXSD6oTo6b1MI?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['angularMoment']);

app.controller('Home', function ($scope) {
  $scope.startDate = moment();
  $scope.endDate = moment();
  $scope.updateStart = function () {
    $scope.startDate = moment();
  };
  $scope.updateEnd = function () {
    $scope.endDate = moment();
  };
});

app.directive('dateInput', function () {
  return {
    resolve: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'dateInput.html',
    scope: {
      dateStart: '=',
      dateEnd: '=',
      label: '@'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      var self = this;
      self.update = function (start, end, label) {
        console.debug('DirectiveCtrl.update: ' + start.format('MM-DD-YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
        $scope.dateStart = start;
        $scope.dateEnd = end;
      };
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      element.children('div').children('input').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 5,
        locale: {
          format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
        }
      }, controller.update);
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Home">
  <p>
    Start Date: {{startDate | amParse: 'MM-DD-YYYY'}}
    <br />
    End Date: {{endDate | amParse: 'MM-DD-YYYY' }}
  </p>
  <date-input date-start="startDate" date-end="endDate" label="Schedule"></date-input>
  <button type="button" ng-click="updateStart()">Update Start</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="updateEnd()">Update End</button>
</div>
```

Comment: camelCase is needed for directives. `dateStart` and `dateEnd` become `date-start` and `date-end` respectively.

Comment: @MuliYulzary Thanks, I've updated the code but the issue is still there.

Comment: You also need to tell angular the model has changed so call `$scope.$apply()` in your update function after you're done updating the vars.

Comment: @MuliYulzary Thats the answer. If you add it as the answer I'll accept it.  Thank you! So many hours wasted...

Comment: We all have these moments mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell angular the model has changed so call `$scope.$apply()` in your update function after you're done updating the vars.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.